# Where does Google Drive Api store the access token after authenticating via web browser?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am using the google drive api in a forms application. The app calls a method that is supposed to open the browser and allow you to authenticate the gmail account that the application will use to connect to the google drive api. After you authenticate, the app no longer opens the browser to allow you to authenticate when that particular method that creates the connection is called.

**The problem:** 
I have a new Google drive api client id and secret, I cant get the browser to open and ask me to authenticate when that particular connection method is called. This is causing my app to crash when it tries to connect to the google drive api.

I assume this is because an access token has already been stored on the computer from a previous account that was authenticated via the web browser with the app.

After you authenticate with the Google drive api through the browser, where is the access token stored? I want to remove the access token so next time I run the app, it will hopefully open the browser and letting me authenticate with the new client id and secret that the app is using.

I have already cleared all browser data but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code and what language you are using and the client library

Answer (score 0):

The Google API stores the access token here:

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth
```

If you have trouble with the application not opening a browser windows and prompting you to authenticate with Google, then remove that token and run your app again.